# Check for duplicates in SQLite database before adding row

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm trying to add a row to my database in android with the following code, but I want to make sure that the row does not already exist, how would i do that?

```
void addKey(String key, String value, String table) {

            SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            values.put(KEY_KEY, key);
            values.put(KEY_VALUE, value);

            // Inserting Row
            db.insert(table, null, values);
            db.close(); // Closing database connection          
    }
```

I tried using the following code but I couldn't get it to work

```
public boolean check(String key, String value, String table) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        String sql = "select * from " + table + " where key= " + key + " and value= " + value;
        Cursor cur = db.rawQuery( sql, new String[0] );

        if(cur.getCount() == 0)
        {
            cur.close();
            db.close();
            return false;
        }

        else{
            cur.close();
            db.close();
            return true;
        }

    }
```

The error:

```
12-04 16:34:46.867: E/AndroidRuntime(2743): Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: hi: , while compiling: select * from tableOne where key= hi and value= baby
12-04 16:34:46.867: E/AndroidRuntime(2743):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.native_compile(Native Method)
12-04 16:34:46.867: E/AndroidRuntime(2743):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.compile(SQLiteCompiledSql.java:92)
12-04 16:34:46.867: E/AndroidRuntime(2743):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.<init>(SQLiteCompiledSql.java:65)
12-04 16:34:46.867: E/AndroidRuntime(2743):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:83)
12-04 16:34:46.867: E/AndroidRuntime(2743):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:49)
12-04 16:34:46.867: E/AndroidRuntime(2743):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:42)
12-04 16:34:46.867: E/AndroidRuntime(2743):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1428)
12-04 16:34:46.867: E/AndroidRuntime(2743):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery(SQLiteDatabase.java:1396)
```

Comment: Use parameters... Like `key=?` assuming that key is string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to either format the string correctly in SQL (which involves quoting the string itself, and any quotes in the string), or use *parameters* to pass the string into the database:

```java
String sql = "SELECT * FROM " + table + " WHERE key=? AND value=?";
Cursor cur = db.rawQuery(sql, new String[] { key, value });
```

If only the value changes, do you really want to insert another record with the same key? Or would you rather update that record?